# Why is my flight script not functioning correctly?

Tags: roblox

I'm making a flight script to use  for ProtoSmasher and it's not working as intended. I want it to have a toggle button (G) and then be able to fly with a button (W). Instead of that, to get it to work I have to hold W and then press G; but if I try to let go of w to stop in the air I have to press G again.

```
local plr = game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer
local char = plr.Character
local hum = char.Humanoid
local Torso = char.HumanoidRootPart
local Mouse = plr:GetMouse()
local toggle = false
local wToggle = false

Mouse.KeyDown:Connect(function(key)
    if key == "w" then
        wToggle = true
    end
    if key == "g" then
        if toggle == false then
            toggle = true
            local BV = Instance.new("BodyVelocity",Torso)
            BV.MaxForce = Vector3.new(math.huge,math.huge,math.huge)
            while wToggle == true do
                BV.Velocity = Mouse.Hit.lookVector*200
                wait()
            end
        end
        if toggle == true then
            toggle = false
            Torso:FindFirstChildOfClass("BodyVelocity"):remove()
        end
    end
end)

Mouse.KeyUp:Connect(function(key)
    if key == "w" then
        wToggle = false
    end
end)
```

Comment: If you want to hit `G` once and then use `W` to fly I would set `G` to only be a boolean toggle for turning flight on or off and put the actual flying code into `W`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to connect to keyboard key presses, but you are doing so in the event listener for mouse button presses.

Try something like this :

```
local isFlying = false

local function onKeyPress(actionName, userInputState, inputObject)
    local isKeyDown = userInputState == Enum.UserInputState.Begin
    local isKeyUp = userInputState == Enum.UserInputState.End

    if actionName == "toggleFlight" then
        if isKeyUp then
            isFlying = not isFlying
        end

    elseif actionName == "fly" then
        if isKeyDown then
            -- start flying forward
        elseif isKeyUp then
            -- stop flying
        end
    end
end

-- listen for keyboard input
game.ContextActionService:BindAction("toggleFlight", onKeyPress, false, Enum.KeyCode.G)
game.ContextActionService:BindAction("fly",          onKeyPress, false, Enum.KeyCode.W)
```